# IPV4 Connectivity isn't working, IPV6 working fine

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet, ipv6, ipv4

I have set up a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS, however I run into some connectivity issues, especially regarding IPV4. It seems however that IPV6 is working correctly.

Here is an example ping to google.com

```
ubuntu@partagedebonsplants:~$ nslookup google.com

Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.206.238
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4007:818::200e

ubuntu@partagedebonsplants:~$ ping google.com

PING google.com(par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=11.7 ms
ping 64 bytes from par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=11.7 ms
64 bytes from par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=10.8 ms
64 bytes from par21s20-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4007:818::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=11.8 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.736/11.340/11.796/0.478 ms

ubuntu@partagedebonsplants:~$ ping google.com -4

PING google.com (216.58.206.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
From partagedebonsplants.home (192.168.1.26) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From partagedebonsplants.home (192.168.1.26) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From partagedebonsplants.home (192.168.1.26) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3055ms
pipe 3
```

The Pi is assigned a static IPV4 address through our router parameters, and there are several other computers on the same network running Windows/mobile devices which access IPV4/IPV6 addresses without issue.

There is nothing special in the firewall rules nor in the `etc/hosts` file. Here is the output from `ifconfig`

```
ubuntu@partagedebonsplants:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.26  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a01:cb14:b7:1200:e65f:1ff:fe16:64b1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe16:64b1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:5f:01:16:64:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2531  bytes 226639 (226.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 236  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1004  bytes 100909 (100.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 347  bytes 30041 (30.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 347  bytes 30041 (30.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e4:5f:01:16:64:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that pinging local addresses works fine (i.e. `ping 192.168.1.1`)

Thanks a lot for your help

EDIT - Additional information

Here is the output of `traceroute 215.58.206.238`

```
ubuntu@partagedebonsplants:~$ traceroute 215.58.206.238

traceroute to 215.58.206.238 (215.58.206.238), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  partagedebonsplants.home (192.168.1.26)  3073.222 ms !H  3073.116 ms !H  3073.066 ms !H
```

Answer (score 0):

(Q) Do you think that IPv4 isn't working because of ping using IPv6 address?

The format of the ping command I think should be:

```
ping -4 google.com
# or
ping 216.58.206.238
```

When DNS is used to resolve google.com, and both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are available, the OS based on the stacks enabled and user/app preferences decide on using IPv6 unless IPv4 is "selected".

Since you have an IPv4 address and you can ping something/anything `ping 192.168.1.1` means that your IPv4 stack is working. IMO.

The output of ifconfig (thanks for including it) says your local IPv4 address is `192.168.1.26`.  So if you pinged `192.168.1.1` which is your router than your stack is working (most likely).

Try fixing the ping command as suggested above or just try `ping 216.58.206.238` to eliminate the DNS lookup.

Also try

```
traceroute 215.58.206.238
```

NOTE: I needed to install traceroute using `sudo apt install inetutils-traceroute` before I could run that.

Traceroute shows you the network routers used to reach your destination.  If more than one show up then your IPv4 is working and there is a problem with routing.  (I'm perhaps oversimplifying).

Update your question by adding the output of these commands and let everyone know what happened, and we can take the next steps.

I'll continue to update this answer based on what I see in your question.

And I see you are brand new to StackOverflow, so welcome aboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I have included both ping and ping -4 in my question. It all comes from the fact that I can ping/curl ipv6 enabled websites or dual stack websites but not ipv4 (I.e. I can ping Google but not GitHub nor Google -4 as seen above). It seems that ipv4 works but not for outbound connections. I am going to see if there is something wrong with the router however other devices on the network have no issues with ipv4

Comment: I have resorted to reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04, and it solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.   In the future, try making the title a question.  Making it a question will help other people find the answer to the same question that you had.  Best wishes, and good luck with the project.  So your question might be "Why doesn't IPv4 work on `Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS`.  Then the rest of what you had is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 LTS solved the issue. There most likely was a configuration error on my end. Thanks for the input

Comment: Glad you got it working.